# I am doing a project in android. I made a app in which a floatingActionButton is not working when clicked. Its showing App keeps stopping

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, android-developer-api

I am doing a project in android. I made a app in which a floatingActionButton is not working when clicked. Its showing App keeps stopping.
When i click the button the setOnClickListener works and the desired page is shown but then a dialog box appears that says " APP keeps stopping".

Github project link: [https://github.com/Xander1540/Xold[enter](https://github.com/Xander1540/Xold%5Benter) link description here][1](https://github.com/Xander1540/Xold)

Here the floatingActionButton named `sellFab` when triggered works but then the app stops responding.

```
MainActivity.kt

package com.example.xold.activities

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.xold.R
import com.example.xold.Utils
import com.example.xold.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.xold.fragments.AccountFragment
import com.example.xold.fragments.ChatsFragment
import com.example.xold.fragments.HomeFragment
import com.example.xold.fragments.MyAdsFragment
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    companion object{

        private const val TAG = "MAIN_TAG"
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        if(firebaseAuth.currentUser ==null){
            startLoginOptions()
        }else{

            updateFcmToken()
            askNotificationPermission()
        }

        showHomeFragment()

        binding.bottomNv.setOnItemSelectedListener{item ->
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_home -> {
                showHomeFragment()
                true
            }
            R.id.menu_chats -> {

                if(firebaseAuth.currentUser==null){
                    Utils.toast(this, "Login Required")
                    startLoginOptions()

                    false
                }else{
                    showChatsFragment()
                    true
                }
            }
            R.id.menu_my_ads ->{

                if(firebaseAuth.currentUser==null){
                    Utils.toast(this, "Login Required")
                    startLoginOptions()

                    false
                }else {
                    showMyAdsFragment()

                    true
                }
            }
            R.id.menu_account ->{

                if(firebaseAuth.currentUser==null){
                    Utils.toast(this, "Login Required")
                    startLoginOptions()

                    false
                }else{
                    showAccountFragment()
                    true
                }
            }
            else ->{
                false
            }
        }
        }


        binding.sellFab.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, AdCreateActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("isEditMode", true)
            startActivity(intent)

        }

    }

    private fun showHomeFragment(){

        binding.toolbarTitleTv.text= "Home"

        val fragment = HomeFragment()
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(binding.fragmentsFl.id, fragment, "HomeFragment")
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

    private fun showChatsFragment(){
        binding.toolbarTitleTv.text= "Chats"

        val fragment = ChatsFragment()
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(binding.fragmentsFl.id, fragment, "ChatsFragment")
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

    private fun showMyAdsFragment(){
        binding.toolbarTitleTv.text= "My Ads"

        val fragment = MyAdsFragment()
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(binding.fragmentsFl.id, fragment, "MyAdsFragment")
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

    private fun showAccountFragment(){
        binding.toolbarTitleTv.text= "Account"

        val fragment = AccountFragment()
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(binding.fragmentsFl.id, fragment, "AccountFragment")
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

    private fun startLoginOptions(){
        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginOptionsActivity::class.java))
    }

    private fun updateFcmToken() {

        val myUid = "${firebaseAuth.uid}"
        Log.d(TAG, "updateFcmToken: ")

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token
            .addOnSuccessListener {fcmToken->

                Log.d(TAG, "updateFcmToken: fcmToken $fcmToken")
                val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                hashMap["fcmToken"] = "$fcmToken"

                val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                ref.child(myUid)
                    .updateChildren(hashMap)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {

                        Log.d(TAG, "updateFcmToken: FCM Token Update to db success")
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                        Log.e(TAG, "updateFcmToken: ", e)
                    }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->

                Log.e(TAG, "updateFcmToken: ", e)
            }
    }
    
    private fun askNotificationPermission() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
            }
        }
    }

    private val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
    ) { isGranted ->

            Log.d(TAG, "requestPermissionLauncher: isGranted: $isGranted")
    }

}
```

AdCreateActivity.kt

```
package com.example.xold.activities

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.PopupMenu
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import com.example.xold.R
import com.example.xold.Utils
import com.example.xold.adapters.AdapterImagePicked
import com.example.xold.databinding.ActivityAdCreateBinding
import com.example.xold.models.ModelImagePicked
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage

class AdCreateActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAdCreateBinding

    private companion object{
        private const val TAG = "ADD_CREATE_TAG"
    }

    private lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog

    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    private var imageUri: Uri? = null

    private lateinit var imagePickedArrayList: ArrayList<ModelImagePicked>

    private lateinit var adapterImagePicked: AdapterImagePicked

    private var isEditMode = false

    private var adIdForEditing = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityAdCreateBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait...")
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        val adapterCategories = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_category_act, Utils.categories)
        binding.categoryAct.setAdapter(adapterCategories)

        val adapterConditions = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_condition_act, Utils.condition)
        binding.conditionAct.setAdapter(adapterConditions)

        isEditMode = intent.getBooleanExtra("isEditMode", false)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: isEditMode: $isEditMode")

        if(isEditMode){

            adIdForEditing = intent.getStringExtra("adId") ?: ""

            loadAdDetails()

            binding.toolbarTitleTv.text = "Update Ad"
            binding.postAdBtn.text = "Update Ad"
        }else{

            binding.toolbarTitleTv.text = "Create Ad"
            binding.postAdBtn.text = "Post Ad"
        }
        
        imagePickedArrayList = ArrayList()

        loadImages()


        binding.toolbarBackBtn.setOnClickListener {
            onBackPressed()
        }

        binding.toolbarAdImageBtn.setOnClickListener {

            showImagePickOptions()
        }

        binding.locationAct.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(this, LocationPickerActivity::class.java)
            locationPickerActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
        }

        binding.postAdBtn.setOnClickListener {

            validateData()
        }

    }

    private val locationPickerActivityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){result->
            Log.d(TAG, "locationPickerActivityResultLauncher: ")

            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

                val data = result.data

                if (data!=null) {
                    latitude = data.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0.0)
                    longitude = data.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.0)
                    address = data.getStringExtra("address") ?: ""

                    Log.d(TAG, "locationPickerActivityResultLauncher: latitude: $latitude")
                    Log.d(TAG, "locationPickerActivityResultLauncher: longitude: $longitude")
                    Log.d(TAG, "locationPickerActivityResultLauncher: address: $address")

                    binding.locationAct.setText(address)
                }
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "locationPickerActivityResultLauncher: cancelled")
                Utils.toast(this, "Cancelled")
            }
        }

    private fun loadImages() {

        Log.d(TAG, "loadImages: ")

        adapterImagePicked = AdapterImagePicked(this, imagePickedArrayList, adIdForEditing)

        binding.imageRv.adapter = adapterImagePicked
    }

    private fun showImagePickOptions(){
        Log.d(TAG, "showImagePickOptions: ")

        val popupMenu = PopupMenu(this, binding.toolbarAdImageBtn)

        popupMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Camera")
        popupMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Gallery")

        popupMenu.show()

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item->

            val itemId = item.itemId

            if(itemId==1){

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU){

                    val cameraPermissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    requestCameraPermission.launch(cameraPermissions)
                }
                else{

                    val cameraPermissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    requestCameraPermission.launch(cameraPermissions)
                }

            }else if(itemId==2){

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU){
                    pickImageGallery()
                }
                else{

                    val storagePermission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    requestStoragePermission.launch(storagePermission)

                }
            }
            true
        }
    }

    private val requestStoragePermission = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ){ isGranted->
        Log.d(TAG, "requestStoragePermission: isGranted: $isGranted")

        if (isGranted){

            pickImageGallery()
        }else{

            Utils.toast(this, "Storage permission denied..")
        }
    }

    private val requestCameraPermission = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
    ){ result->
        Log.d(TAG, "requestCameraPermission: result: $result")

        var areAllGranted = true
        for (isGranted in result.values){
            areAllGranted = areAllGranted && isGranted
        }

        if (areAllGranted){

            pickImageCamera()
        }else{

            Utils.toast(this, "Camera or Storage or both permission denied...")
        }
    }

    private fun pickImageGallery(){

        Log.d(TAG, "pickImageGallery: ")

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        galleryActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)

    }

    private fun pickImageCamera(){

        Log.d(TAG, "pickImageCamera: ")

        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "TEMP_IMAGE_TITLE")
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "TEMP_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION")

        imageUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)

        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
        cameraActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
    }

    private val galleryActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ){ result->

        Log.d(TAG, "galleryActivityResultLauncher: ")

        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

            val data = result.data

            imageUri = data!!.data
            Log.d(TAG, "galleryActivityResultLauncher: imageUri: $imageUri")

            val timestamp = "${Utils.getTimestamp()}"

            val modelImagePicked = ModelImagePicked(timestamp, imageUri, null, false)

            imagePickedArrayList.add(modelImagePicked)

            loadImages()
        } else {

            Utils.toast(this, "Cancelled..!")
        }

    }

    private val cameraActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ){ result->

        Log.d(TAG, "cameraActivityResultLauncher: ")
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

            Log.d(TAG, "cameraActivityResultLauncher: imageUri: $imageUri")

            val timestamp = "${Utils.getTimestamp()}"

            val modelImagePicked = ModelImagePicked(timestamp, imageUri, null, false)

            imagePickedArrayList.add(modelImagePicked)

            loadImages()
        } else {

            Utils.toast(this, "Cancelled...!")
        }
    }

    private var brand = ""
    private var category = ""
    private var condition = ""
    private var address = ""
    private var price = ""
    private var title = ""
    private var description  = ""
    private var latitude = 0.0
    private var longitude = 0.0


    private fun validateData() {

        Log.d(TAG, "validateData: ")

        brand = binding.brandEt.text.toString().trim()
        category = binding.categoryAct.text.toString().trim()
        condition = binding.conditionAct.text.toString().trim()
        address = binding.locationAct.text.toString().trim()
        price = binding.priceEt.text.toString().trim()
        title = binding.titleEt.text.toString().trim()
        description = binding.descriptionEt.text.toString().trim()


        if(brand.isEmpty()){

            binding.brandEt.error = "Enter Brand"
            binding.brandEt.requestFocus()
        } else if(category.isEmpty()){

            binding.categoryAct.error = "Choose Category"
            binding.categoryAct.requestFocus()

        } else if(condition.isEmpty()){

            binding.conditionAct.error = "Choose Condition"
            binding.conditionAct.requestFocus()

        } else if (title.isEmpty()){

            binding.titleEt.error = "Enter Title"
            binding.titleEt.requestFocus()

        }else if(description.isEmpty()){

            binding.descriptionEt.error = "Enter Description"
            binding.descriptionEt.requestFocus()

        }else{

            if (isEditMode){
                updateAd()
            }else{
                postAd()
            }
            postAd()
        }
    }

    private fun postAd() {

        Log.d(TAG, "postAd: ")

        progressDialog.setMessage("Publishing Ad")
        progressDialog.show()

        val timestamp = Utils.getTimestamp()

        val refAds= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads")

        val keyId = refAds.push().key

        val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
        hashMap["id"] = "$keyId"
        hashMap["uid"] = "${firebaseAuth.uid}"
        hashMap["brand"] = "$brand"
        hashMap["category"] = "$category"
        hashMap["condition"] = "$condition"
        hashMap["address"] = "$address"
        hashMap["price"] = "$price"
        hashMap["title"] = "$title"
        hashMap["description"] = "$description"
        hashMap["status"] = "${Utils.AD_STATUS_AVAILABLE}"
        hashMap["timestamp"] = timestamp
        hashMap["latitude"] = latitude
        hashMap["longitude"] = longitude


        refAds.child(keyId!!)
            .setValue(hashMap)
            .addOnSuccessListener {

                Log.d(TAG, "postAd: Ad Published")
                uploadImagesStorage(keyId)

            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e->
                Log.e(TAG, "postAd: ", )
                progressDialog.dismiss()
                Utils.toast(this, "Failed due to ${e.message}")

            }
    }

    private fun updateAd(){
        Log.d(TAG, "updateAd: ")

        progressDialog.setMessage("Updating Ad..!")
        progressDialog.show()

        val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
        hashMap["brand"] = "$brand"
        hashMap["category"] = "$category"
        hashMap["condition"] = "$condition"
        hashMap["address"] = "$address"
        hashMap["price"] = "$price"
        hashMap["title"] = "$title"
        hashMap["description"] = "$description"
        hashMap["latitude"] = latitude
        hashMap["longitude"] = longitude

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads")
        ref.child(adIdForEditing)
            .updateChildren(hashMap)
            .addOnSuccessListener {

                Log.d(TAG, "updateAd: Ad Updated..!")
                progressDialog.dismiss()

                uploadImagesStorage(adIdForEditing)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {e->
                Log.e(TAG, "updateAd: ", e)
                progressDialog.dismiss()
                Utils.toast(this, "Failed to update the Ad due to ${e.message}")
            }
    }

    private fun uploadImagesStorage(adId: String){

        for(i in imagePickedArrayList.indices){

            val modelImagePicked = imagePickedArrayList[i]

            if(!modelImagePicked.fromInternet){
                val imageName = modelImagePicked.id

                val filePathAndName = "Ads/$imageName"
                val imageIndexForProgress = i + 1

                val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(filePathAndName)
                storageReference.putFile(modelImagePicked.imageUri!!)
                    .addOnProgressListener { snapshot->

                        val progress= 100* snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalByteCount

                        Log.d(TAG, "uploadImagesStorage: progress: $progress")
                        val message = "uploading $imageIndexForProgress of ${imagePickedArrayList.size} images...Progress ${progress.toInt()}"
                        Log.d(TAG, "uploadImagesStorage: message: $message")

                        progressDialog.setMessage(message)
                        progressDialog.show()

                    }
                    .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot->
                        Log.d(TAG, "uploadImagesStorage: onSuccess")

                        val uriTask = taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl
                        while (!uriTask.isSuccessful);
                        val uploadedImageUrl = uriTask.result

                        if(uriTask.isSuccessful){

                            val hasMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                            hasMap["id"] = "${modelImagePicked.id}"
                            hasMap["imageUrl"] = "$uploadedImageUrl"


                            val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads")
                            ref.child(adId).child("Images")
                                .child(imageName)
                                .updateChildren(hasMap)
                        }

                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener{ e->

                        Log.e(TAG, "uploadImagesStorage: ", e)
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                    }
            }

        }
    }

    private fun loadAdDetails(){
        Log.d(TAG, "loadAdDetails: ")

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads")
        ref.child(adIdForEditing)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{

                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                    val brand = "${snapshot.child("brand").value}"
                    val category = "${snapshot.child("category").value}"
                    val condition = "${snapshot.child("condition").value}"
                    latitude = (snapshot.child("latitude").value as Double) ?: 0.0
                    longitude = (snapshot.child("longitude").value as Double) ?: 0.0
                    val address = "${snapshot.child("address").value}"
                    val price = "${snapshot.child("price").value}"
                    val title = "${snapshot.child("title").value}"
                    val description = "${snapshot.child("description").value}"

                    binding.brandEt.setText(brand)
                    binding.categoryAct.setText(category)
                    binding.conditionAct.setText(condition)
                    binding.locationAct.setText(address)
                    binding.priceEt.setText(price)
                    binding.titleEt.setText(title)
                    binding.descriptionEt.setText(description)

                    val refImages = snapshot.child("Images").ref
                    refImages.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{

                        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                            for (ds in snapshot.children){

                                val id = "${ds.child("id").value}"
                                val imageUrl = "${ds.child("imageUrl").value}"

                                val modelImagePicked = ModelImagePicked(id, null, imageUrl, true)
                                imagePickedArrayList.add(modelImagePicked)
                            }

                            loadImages()
                        }

                        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                        }
                    })
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                }

            })

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it stopping? What exception does the Logcat contain?

Comment: I got the bug in the code and resolved it.
`
    binding.sellFab.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, AdCreateActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("isEditMode", false)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
`
In the MainActivity.kt file while calling the intent I was giving the boolean value "true" to putExtra() function instead I had to give "false". Now the code is correct.
 @le

Answer (score -1):

Define AdCreateActivity to your manifest file under the application tag, if you didn't.

Comment: I already defined AdCreateActivity in manifest file under application tag.